# Excel 2013 how plot two or more data results, y-values, versus same x-axis on same chart

Tags: multiple-columns, scatter-plot

Excel 2013. I plotted two different dependent variables (y-value) versus their shared fixed variable (x-axis). This used to be easy for me with prior Excel versions. But the only success I've had so far with the Windows 365 version of Excel is to get bars shown for one variable and the much preferable markers for the other. Most of the questions I've found in here seem to use VBA or additional software programs which I am certain, for what i want, to be unnecessary. Will someone please tell me the easy Excel 2013 procedure for doing this? And please reassure me that when I learn how to use those new off-to-the-side areas and icons, that I will once again love graphing capabilities of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you want correctly then

1. select the columns of data (eg x,y1,y2)
2. select the INSERT tab
3. click the insert Line Chart icon (zig-zag lines) in the 'charts grouping of icons)
4. select the sub-type of line chart
5. your default chart appears, now edit it ...
6. Right-click on the body of the chart and select the 'select data' option
7. deselect or 'remove' your x axis variable from the 'legend entries' group on the right if it appears there
8. on the right hand side "horizontal (category) axis" click the edit link then select the x-axis data including the column heading. Excel should then populate the field for you with something like this: '=Sheet1!$A:$A'
9. click ok

Hopefully you now have what you want.

No doubt there are other ways of doing this but this is what I usually do e.g. if I want to plot multiple variable readings against time on one graph.